Never ask my a question, but is that right
My ubuntu install and uses in virtualbox but I install in virtual box it never ask me choose language and any question, I want to know is that right?

How do you know that the Ubuntu installer has started installing the Ubuntu guest OS in the first place? Maybe you're just running an Ubuntu live session from the Ubuntu installation media. Or maybe you haven't added an Ubuntu iso file to the virtual optical drive in VirtualBox.

If I remember correctly, VirtualBox includes an automatic installer for Ubuntu. If you turn that on, VirtualBox will install Ubuntu for you. Did you turn on the Unattended Installation mode?

It is a bit unclear from the question whether you're having an issue preventing you from installing an ubuntu VM or you're missing a functionality you need or just checking if everything was okay with your installation. However, if I understand correctly you expect to see the installation menu with choice settings to personalize your installation. As @JörgWMittag mentioned, it is possible you have the VirtualBox auto installation / unattended installation turned on so it sets all parameters to some preconfigured defaults for you and skips the installation menu part.
